# Kiel oni diras seka nazmukaĵo en la naztruo?

Tags: single-word-requests

Kiel oni diras seka nazmukaĵo en la naztruo?  
(booger/bogey/crotte de nez/Popel)

Answer (score 2):

Vi jam trovis la vorton: *nazmukaĵo*. Tio jam celas la sekiĝintan reston de la fluida nazmuko. Atentu la elementon *-aĵ-*.

Answer (score 1):

Mi detale diskutis tiun demandon en januaro kun Bertilo (PMEG), Erinja (lernu.net), kaj aliaj. Estis multaj proponoj (mukaĵo, mukokrusto, naz-koboldo). Mi (kaj verŝajne ankaŭ Boris Kolker) diras **mukero**.

"Muko" jam estas substanco, do ne estas klare kion aldonas la elemento -aĵ- (nazmukaĵo).

Hazarde, la tagon antaŭ ol Erinja levis la temon en Facebook, mi skribis la jenon.

> Nu, mukero (laŭ mi) estas aparte nombrebla ero de muko - kaj (laŭ mi) sekvas de tiu difino ke ĝi estu sufiĉe solida por stari kiel propra aĵo - do, ne guto de muko, kaj ne disrompebla krusto. (Tamen, ja eblas rompi mukeron per ungo aŭ tranĉilo - en tiu okazo vi havas nun du mukerojn.) ... nu, aŭ eventuale, du duonojn de unu mukero.

Mi ne volas harofendi (nek mukofendi) pril la demando kiel mola povas esti mukero... nek fari linion inter "firma guto" kaj "tre mola mukero."

Comment: Sincere, mi opinias _mukero_ nekontentiga. Ĉar muko estas likvo, _mukeron_ mi komprenus kiel _akveron_, _pluveron_, do guton. Sekiĝinta resto de muko estas io alia, kaj miaopinie _nazmukaĵo_ tre bone trafas tion, ĝi estas aĵo el nazmuko, do mi ne vidas vortfaradan problemon.

Comment: @CyrilBrosch - Mi ne volas harofendi (nek mukofendi) pril la demando kiel mola povas esti mukero... nek fari linion inter "firma guto" kaj "tre mola mukero." Laux PIV, muko estas "Pli-malpli viskeca substanco" ne nepre "likvo."